# All Angular Masonry packages give me the same install error across multiple apps

Tags: angular, npm, masonry

Upon install any of the popular masonry packages for angular masonry, I get the same error every time and I'm at the point of ripping my hair out

```
Unexpected token d in JSON at position 702 while parsing near '...get-size":"~1.2.2","desandro-get-style-p...'
```

[ng-masonry-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-masonry-grid), [ngx-masonry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-masonry), [ngx-masonry-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-masonry-gallery), and every other masonry package I've tried installing has given me the *same exact error*. I'm assuming because all of them use the same code at some point, but I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This has been driving me crazy for weeks, but it seems like running `npm cache clear --force` fixes this issue.

No idea why but it works